# asp.net c# 404 page not found

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can any one help me with the following error.

When I try to type my link like this **`localhost:1297/Index.aspx`**, it open properly.

But when I try to open the link like this

**`http://localhost:1297/Index.aspxabc`**

it throws `404 error`.

I tried to handle this error by add a code in web.config as shown below :

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error.aspx">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/404.aspx"/>
</customErrors>
```

But still it is showing the same error :

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cY9v7.png)

Please following the link which shows the error

Comment: Does the `404.aspx` file actually exist in your project?

Comment: Yes, 404.aspx is created in my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this i think it will solve the issue

```
 <configuration>

   <system.web>
      <customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">
         <error statusCode="404" redirect="404.aspx" />
      </customErrors>
   </system.web>

   <system.webServer>
      <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
         <remove statusCode="404"/>
         <error statusCode="404" path="/404.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
      </httpErrors>
   </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Comment: make sure web config look like this

Comment: Thank you so much, it is working properly and show me 404.aspx page.

Answer (score 0):

You can set custom error pages using IIS
Refer
https://www.bruceclay.com/blog/microsoft-iis-custom-404-error-page-configuration/